# Cannot access react state from callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, visnetwork

I have the following components:

```
const ParentComponent: React.FC = () => {
    // Somewhere in the code, I set this to some value
    const [newType, setNewType] = useState<any>(undefined);

    // Somewhere in the code, I set this to true
    const [enableAddEdge, setEnableAddEdge] = useState(false);

    const addEdge = (data: any) => {
        console.log("newType", newType); // This is undefined
    }

    return (
    ...
        <VisNetwork 
            newType={newType}
            onAddEdge={addEdge}
            enableAddEdge={enableAddEdge}
        />
    ...
    )
}
export default ParentComponent;

interface Props {
    newType: any;
    onAddEdge: (data: any) => void;
    enableAddEdge: boolean;
}
const VisNetwork: React.FC<Props> = (props: Props) => {
    const options: any = {
        // Some vis-network specific option configuration
        manipulation: {
            addEdge: (data: any, callback: any) => props.onAddEdge(data);
        }
    }
    ...
    // Some code to create the network and pass in the options
    const network = new vis.Network(container, networkData, options);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (props.enableAddEdge) {
            // This confirms that indeed newType has value
            console.log("newType from addEdge", props.newType);

            // Call reference to network (I name it currentNetwork)
            // This will enable the adding of edge in the network.  
            // When the user is done adding the edge,
            // the `addEdge` method in the `options.manipulation` will be called.
            currentNetwork.addEdgeMode();
        }
    }, [props.enableAddEdge])

    useEffect(() => {
        if (props.newType) {
            // This is just to confirm that indeed I am setting the newType value
            console.log("newType from visNetwork", props.newType); // This has value
        }
    }, [props.newType]);
}
export default VisNetwork;
```

When the `addEdge` method is called, the `newType` state becomes undefined.  I know about the bind but I don't know if it's possible to use it and how to use it in a functional component.  Please advise on how to obtain the `newType` value.

Also, from `VisNetwork`, I want to access `networkData` state from inside `options.manipulation.addEdge`.  I know it's not possible but any workaround?  I also need to access the `networkData` at this point.

Comment: From the code you provide here, you set `newType` initial value to undefined, so there's no reason `console.log("newType", newType)` to log something else ?

Comment: it is `undefined` when i initialize the state, but eventually i set it to a value.  and i already log the value on `VisNetwork` component.  When the child component call the `onAddEdge` callback, the value I set in the `newType` is lost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to `useRef` in this scenario. It appears `const network = new vis.Network(container, networkData, options);` uses the options from the first render only. Or something similar is going on.

It's likely to do with there being a closure around `newType` in the `addEdge` function. So it has stale values: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#why-am-i-seeing-stale-props-or-state-inside-my-function

In order to combat this, you need to `useRef` to store the latest value of `newType`. The reference is mutable, so it can always store the current value of newType without re-rendering.

```
// Somewhere in the code, I set this to some value
const [newType, setNewType] = useState<any>(undefined);

const newTypeRef = useRef(newType);
useEffect(() => {
  // Ensure the ref is always at the latest value
  newTypeRef.current = newType;
}, [newType])

const addEdge = (data: any) => {
    console.log("newType", newTypeRef.current); // This is undefined
}
```